Advice on the approach for bidirectional port forwarding
I have the following setup:
Device D connected to Computer B with Ethernet cable
I need to remotely communicate with Device D from my Computer A through Computer B
The communication happens only on 2 ports, one for UDP and one for TCP
Computer B is not in my control and I can't change system network settings there, but I can ask to run some code/program without admin rights
I tested the setup when Computer B is within my local network (same wifi) and firewall disabled. Then I run a python script on B to listed to ports U for UDP and T for TCP, forward all the packets to Device D and then wait for response and send response back from B to A

Question 1: Does my testing setup make sense?
Question 2: For real world scenario, when B is not on my local network and has firewall enabled, what could be the approach to setup communication A <-> B <-> D? I though about relay server which accepts connections and then I could transfer all the data through it. It would require to run a program on B that connects to relay server R, then R waits for the data coming from A to forward it to B, then B forward received data to D and send response back to R which in turn send it back to A
So it looks like A <-> R <-> B <-> D
The idea is that it doesn't require any network settings changes on B as the application we run on B connects to R.
Is there better/easier approach to setup this? Or maybe some existing standard software?



Is there better/easier approach to setup this?

In the real world its usually easier to talk to whoever you need to talk to, to either get access to the required system (B) or to purchase some new hardware so you can establish the connection "properly" using the routing capabilities of system B or through new dedicated hardware.
Failing that, for TCP connections a surprising number of problems are trivially solvable using SSH tunnels.
UDP is more challenging, I would start by pushing back on that, to see if it really needs to be UDP or could be changed to TCP, however there are some kludgey solutions for running UDP down TCP sockets if you really need to.
--
Unfortunately your question is very generic, so my generic answer is "don't do it" - back in the day I have written my fair share of "dumb proxies" (those that just forward packets) - I just don't see the need any more, because .....
Usually using the right tool for the job (network routing) is the quickest, simplest and least error prone. If you have a specific use case then, please update your question to indicate why you need to do something special.

Thanks for feedback. To be more specific I'm now working on a remote car coding tool for my friend. B is a customer computer and D is their car computer. It means they are not constant, they come and go after the service is done. Currently my friend does everything through remote desktop, but it requires to transfer all the needed files and programs to customer computer. Instead we are looking for a way to just use customer computer as a router to the car computer. For the beginning we need to forward 2 ports used by the main coding program, 1 TCP and 1 UDP
